# Automatic clearing of v-textarea content after a certain time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-textarea, I write something to area and if I do not any action, in v-textarea context must be cleared automatic after a certain time (2 minutes). How can I do it?

[image: For example I want to remove Hello' 2 minutes later.]

```
<v-textarea
          v-model.trim="text"
          clearable
          :label="modeLabel"
      >
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this with a timer.

```
<v-textarea
  v-model.trim="text"
  clearable
  :label="modeLabel"
  @change="clearHandler(event)"
>

var timerID = null;

function clearHandler() {

    if (timerID) {
        clearTimeout(timerID);
    }

    // create a timer to clear the textarea by setting the model to empty string
    timerID = setTimeout(() => {
        this.text = "";
    }, 120000);

}
```

Also, I would use `this.timerID` or a `ref` variable, instead of `var` like my example, depending on what version of vue you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I've created this with a simple watcher. First, we create a function that includes the timeout. After that we create a watcher triggered to `val`. In this watcher, we call the timeout and after that clear the timeout. The reason for this is that we want it to re-run the function. The watcher also watches the value, if the user enters sth, the timeout will be canceled.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      val: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    timeout() {
      return setTimeout(() => {
        this.val = ''
      }, 5000)
    }
  },
  watch: {
    val: {
      handler() {
        this.timeout()
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="val" />
</div>
```